# How to filter nested object using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have an object, which looks like this:

```
{
    'somename1':{
        status:'success',
        data:{
            key:'value1',
            field2:'',
            field3:'',
            field4:'',
            field5:'',
            recordSts:'done',
        }
    },
    'someOtherName':{
        status:'success',
        data:{
            key:'value2',
            field2:0,
            field3:'',
            recordSts:'progress',
            field5:'',
            field6:0,
        }
    }
}
```

In this object, I have two fields `key` and `recordSts`, which are `not null` if the status is `success`.

I want to filter this object using lodash and the output should look like this

```
{
    'somename1':{
        status:'success',
        data:{
            key:'value1',
            status:'value1',
        }
    },
    'someOtherName':{
        status:'success',
        data:{
            key:'value1',
            status:'value1',
        }
    }
}
```

Simply I want to delete the keys which having `null` or `empty` or `0` values.

I tried this:

```
_.map(records, 'key'); //records contains my input object
```

But it gives only the value of one field, instead, I want the name of the field and the second field also. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Loop over your object check properties and delete if needed

Comment: Had the same question.
I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52956848/5654642

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_.pickBy` with our custom `predicate`, like

```
_.forEach(records, function(record) {
  record.data = _.pickBy(record.data, function(val) {
      return !!val;
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `_.omitBy` to remove falsy values

```
let res = _.forOwn(records, o => {
    o.data = _.omitBy(o.data, v => {
    return !v;
  });
    return o;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mapValues()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mapValues), [assign()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#assign), and [pickBy()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#pickBy):

```
_.mapValues(
  records, 
  r => _.assign({}, r, { data: _.pickBy(r.data) })
);
```

This produces a new `records` object, without mutating the original. What I like about `pickBy()` is that by default, it'll only return properties with *truthy* values. Notice how we're not passing a predicate? This works because the default predicate is [identity()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#identity), which simply uses the value as a truth test.