# Lodash cloneDeepWith to omit undefined

Tags: javascript, lodash

I wrote a customozer function to omit the undefined values of the object with `cloneDeepWith`. However on the immutable return, it is not digging in recursively. Here is my code:

```
import { cloneDeepWith, pickBy, omit } from 'lodash';

const obj = {
  a0: true,
  b0: true,
  c0: undefined,
  obj1: {
    a1: true,
    b1: true,
    c1: undefined
  }
};

cloneDeepWith(obj, value => {
    const objWithUndefinedValue = pickBy(obj, (value) => value === undefined);
    const keysWithUndefinedValue = Object.keys(objWithUndefinedValue);
    return omit(obj, keysWithUndefinedValue);
});
```

However it doesn't recurse after the first return. Is it possible to accomplish this with lodash stock functionality?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As far as I know `_.cloneDeepWith()` customizer is a bit misleading. The customizer should handle only non object values. If it handles object values, it should also continue the recursion by itself. For example, you can see that as the customizer is called, the cloning is handled by `value.cloneNode(true)`. As you can see only `body` appears in the console.

```js
const { cloneDeepWith, isObject } = _;

function customizer(value) {
  console.log(value);
  if (_.isElement(value)) {
    return value.cloneNode(true);
  }
}
 
var el = _.cloneDeepWith(document.body, customizer);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

However, if you just customize non object values, and return `undefined` for object values, which prompts the method to handle them (documented in [cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#cloneDeep)), it iterates everything:

```js
const { cloneDeepWith, isObject, isUndefined } = _;

const obj = {
  a0: true,
  b0: true,
  c0: undefined,
  obj1: {
    a1: true,
    b1: true,
    c1: undefined
  }
};

const result = cloneDeepWith(obj, v => {
  console.log(v);
  
  return isObject(v) ? undefined : 'custom value';
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

To solve your problem, you can use `_.transform()` recursively to take all values that are not `undefined`:

```js
const { transform, isObject, isUndefined } = _;

const obj = {
  a0: true,
  b0: true,
  c0: undefined,
  obj1: {
    a1: true,
    b1: true,
    c1: undefined
  }
};

const cloneDeepWithoutUndefined = (obj) =>
  transform(obj, (r, v, k) => {
    if(isUndefined(v)) return;
    r[k] = isObject(v) ? cloneDeepWithoutUndefined(v) : v;
  });
  
const result = cloneDeepWithoutUndefined(obj);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome :) I was puzzled by this behavior as well.

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved by using recursively lodash [**transform**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#transform) method via:

```js
const obj = { a0: true, b0: true, c0: undefined, obj1: { a1: true, b1: true, c1: undefined } };

const cloneMe = (obj) => _.transform(obj, (r, v, k) => 
  _.isUndefined(v) ? null : _.isObject(v) ? r[k] = cloneMe(v) : r[k] = v, {})

console.log(cloneMe(obj))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

You could also do this in ES6 only via [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) & [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const obj = { a0: true, b0: true, c0: undefined, obj1: { a1: true, b1: true, c1: undefined } };

const cloneMe = (obj) => {
   return Object.entries(obj).filter(([k,v]) => 
      v != undefined).reduce((r,[k,v]) => {
        r[k] = (v instanceof Object) ? cloneMe(v) : v
        return r
   },{})
}

console.log(cloneMe(obj))
```

You can additionally extend the check for object if `instance of Object` is not sufficient etc.

Comment: This is super cool thank you for both es6 and lodash methods!

Answer (score 2):

There's another alternative using [DeepDash](https://deepdash.io/), which is a standalone, complementary library that offers recursive versions of Lodash functions.

Once DeepDash has been mixed in with Lodash (`deepdash(_)`), you can write a `prune` function like this:

```js
const prune = obj => _.filterDeep(obj, (v) => !_.isUndefined(v))
```

Comment: This is super interesting thank you! Definitely easiest solution!

Comment: Yep! There's lots of good work that's gone into these libraries and they're well tested to handle edge cases, which one could miss if they roll their own. I always prefer libraries, even though it may seem like "just a few lines of code".